# How much are GNU/Linux Desktop distributions dependent to OpenGL?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card

I know that AMD and NVIDIA have bad drivers because their drivers need to make so many things and need to handle so many graphics api (Vulkan, OpenGL) and window system (Xorg, Wayland).

I know that the "new" Vulkan API will help AMD and NVIDIA to make some better Linux drivers. But it will only help if they could stop implementing the OpenGL API and that we have all moved to Wayland, right?

So my question is: How much are GNU/Linux Desktop distributions dependent to OpenGL?
Is the problem related to display servers, widget toolkit, desktop environments or to each of linux applications?

I am not talking about games. Just about simple applications like settings and calendar.

I know that the question is very large, that's why I don't need a deep answer. I just need an help to know where I should look at. Like an introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your applications, the dependency can be from complete to inexistant. The important part is, that desktop environments are applications as well, as are compositors.

If you want a desktop, that works even with the MGA200 or ATI RAGE chips built into many server-mainboards (obviously no OpenGL support), go with soemthing along the lines of LXDE or Xfce.

If you want to run Gnome-Shell with all eye-candy switched on, you will need a card with good OpenGL support - the Mesa implementation just won't cut it.